# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.removeViewAt(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

**Error:**

```
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.removeViewAt (int)' on a null object reference
     W / System.err: at com.arvicapps.geomitric_wallpapers.FavoriteFullImageActivity $ 5.onFavoriteChanged (FavoriteFullImageActivity.java:533)
             at com.github.ivbaranov.mfb.MaterialFavoriteButton.updateFavoriteButton (MaterialFavoriteButton.java:324)
             at com.github.ivbaranov.mfb.MaterialFavoriteButton.setFavorite (MaterialFavoriteButton.java:257)
             at com.github.ivbaranov.mfb.MaterialFavoriteButton.toggleFavorite (MaterialFavoriteButton.java:292)
     W / System.err: at com.github.ivbaranov.mfb.MaterialFavoriteButton $ 1.onClick (MaterialFavoriteButton.java:152)
             at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6659)
             at android.view.View.performClickInternal (View.java:6631)
             at android.view.View.access $ 3100 (View.java:790)
             at android.view.View $ PerformClick.run (View.java:26187)
             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:907)
```

**Here are parts of the code from FavoriteFullImageActivity.java:**

```
@Override protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);  setContentView (R.layout.activity_favorite_full_image);  getSupportActionBar (). hide ();  RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById (R.id.FavoriteCategoryView);  }
```

```
 try {
  recyclerView.removeViewAt (position);  recyclerView.notifyAll ();
 myDbHelper.closeDb ();
 myDbHelper.close ();
 myDbHelper.notifyAll ();
 } catch (NullPointerException nullPointerException) {nullPointerException.printStackTrace ();
  }
```

**How to solve?**

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Did you take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access `child view` without inflating it or that child view does not exist.
set adapter to recycler view

```
recyclerView.adapter=adapter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.removeViewAt (int)' on a null 
object reference
```

It means that the property of `recyclerView` isn't initiated before you use it. Regards this, you need to check the code more carefully.